# How to sort a Vector from a spesific index

Tags: java

We have such method for array

```
Arrays.sort(Object[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex);
```

but to sort a Vector there is only a method using comparator

```
Vector.sort(Comparator c)
```

is there any way to sort a vector but using only fromIndex and toIndex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Vector` isn't used that much. Use `ArrayList`. But to sort a `Vector`, use this:

```
Collections.sort(myVector.subList(startIndex, endIndex));
```

It will change the original `Vector` too.